# Correct redirect URI for Google API and oauth 2.0 for both www and without?

Tags: api, oauth

Do I have to make entries for

`www.example.com` and
`example.com` ?

Because when I have only one of them (say `www.example.com`), login attempt from `example.com` results in `redirect uri mismatch` error.

I can make both entries fine, but is it ok to share `client id, secret..`?
Because it'll be troublesome to use different authentication info for clients who's coming from `www.example.com` and `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

ok...

You can insert multiple uris for `JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS` and `REDIRECT URIS`.

Just insert one per each line....

Why couldn't they just say it there...